# XML validation by XSLT or Schematron in Eclipse XML Editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, xsd, xml-validation, schematron

How can we validate xml document by either schematron or xslt in Eclipse xml editor? The idea is  to extend xml document live validation in eclipse xml editor with some rules based validation method.

Comment: I've retagged your question. This is specific Eclipse IDE question and not general XSLT question.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it myself but you might want to take a look at [Schematron Eclipse Plugin](http://castledesigns.co.uk/schematron-ep.html) from Castle Designs. When I'm forced to use Eclipse I generally use the Eclipse plugin variant of [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/). I've been using oXygen for about six years now so I guess I'm a satisfied user.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but my problem is not to write schema itself. Instead my issue is to validate xml against already written schema. I have to choose either XSLT or Schematron to extend my xsd schema but the question is, which of them could instant validate xml documents in Eclipse? and how?